# CSS Color affects Text Rendering

Tags: css

I swear that I tried finding this answer elsewhere first, I hate having to ask the question myself.

The issue I seem to be experiencing is that when I change to another colour with this font it looks unpolished. The only variable that is different between these two screen shots below is the color attribute...

http://personal.nekonook.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/help.jpg

Top - color: #000000;

Bottom - color: #808080;

Any help I can get would be apreciated, and in case it makes a difference it is an embedded font.

Note: I want to apologize for  the delay in my response - I mistakenly was expecting an e-mail to notify me of answers. Lesson learned - Also I wanted to say thank you to BoltClock's a Unicorn whom I believe embedded my image, I'll keep that code in mind for future reference, thanks!

Comment: In which browsers are you observing this? How are you embedding the font?

Comment: I've seen this happening in Chrome.  I'm not quite sure what the cause of it is though.

Comment: It does seem to be Chrome, blocco - I thought I had seen it in Firefox as well but having gone back and checked the issue is resolved. It's in Google's court now.

Comment: Man, i dont know if this can help but its a try. I use this in my css reset and i guess i never had problems like that in Chrome. So try it: -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  font-weight:100; //may lighten it up
```

also try text-shadow, make the shadow your bg color

Comment: font-weight has been of no use to me, that was the first thing I tried, but thank you very much for that. I will play around with the shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @fontface CSS property? You may want to try the method mentioned in this blog post by Paul Irish:

http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: I know I have not formatted specifically for I.E., and I have not specified what the font format so that may be it.

Comment: It appears to be a Chrome issue, thank you for the syntax though!